# Selected Face color not updating in user interface

Tags: interface, customization, faces, theme

I’m trying to set the selected face color but it is not updating.

Here are my user interface colors and the viewport results:

[image]

The active face is set properly. So are the selected face dots. But the selected face color is not appearing.
I changed all the 3d view colors to bright (in the second image) to see if any affected it, but none of them do.

I know it’s possible because the tutorial I’m following has all selected faces highlighted:
[image]

Any ideas?

**Update:**

So I tried editing another object in the same scene and it looks fine (selected face color correct). When I edit the original object it looks incorrect. In the same viewport even.

It seems that something specific the model itself is overriding the view property?

[image: Another Model looks fine]

Comment: I think you're right, it's gotta be a bug. I went to previous Blender files of the model and in early enough versions the selected face color is correct. When I go to later ones, selected face color does not appear (but on other models in the same file it looks fine).

Comment: and clearing sharp edges doesn't seem to make a difference. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: "something specific the model itself is overriding the view property" this couldn't happen. However - in original model (problem one) try selecting all, pressing `W` and choose *Remove Doubles*.

Comment: 71 vertices removed, but no change with the viewport issue. Good idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the properties region <kbd>P</kbd> there is a panel called Mesh Display, check that the faces overlay is enabled.

[image: overlay option]

Comment: Holy mackerel that did it! And these settings are unique to each model, interesting! Thank you :)